# ASP.NET Active Directory role provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

This is my first time working with ASP.NET Role membership in active directory.

So far i've got a website running, and im able to log in with a active directory user.

My problem is: I cant get "Roles.IsUserInRole" to trigger. It's like it dosent even look at the logged in user for group memberships.

I have been searching for a solution, but the only solution i can find is to write my own membership provider. Is this really neccesary?

I want to control what the users can access with their memberships.
Like if a user is in the "students" security group in the AD then they can only access pages in a student fold in my ASP.NET solution.

I am useing form authentication.

Here is a sample of my webconfig for my rolemanager:

```
    <system.web>
  <roleManager defaultProvider="WindowsProvider"
               enabled="true"
               cacheRolesInCookie="false">
    <providers>
      <add
        name="WindowsProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

and here im trying the IsUserInRole

```
        protected void Login2_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Students"))
            {
            Response.Redirect("../Students/StartPage.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Bonus question: I am only able to login with users from the "Users" container ind my AD. Why cant i login with a user from a OU some levels down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you appear to be using Forms Authentication with `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` for authentication.

This is not compatible with `WindowsTokenRoleProvider`.  To use `WindowsTokenRoleProvider`, which exposes roles based on Windows group membership, you need to be using Windows authentication.

Comment: Thats correct. Not all of my users have a machine in the domain. 
Simply i want an AD user to be able to login with a form and then get redirected to a page they have access to. So i am forced to make a custom membership provider?

Comment: I ended up creating a custom provider. Its was pretty easy actually. 
Simply used this guide: http://slalomdev.blogspot.dk/2008/08/active-directory-role-provider.html

Answer (score 1):

As to your first question, have you already tried to use the group name together with the domain name i.e. `Roles.IsUserInRole(@"DOMAIN\groupName")`?

As to your second question. I assume that you use `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`. If so, I think that you have a connection string in your *web.config* （which is used by the provider）and this connection string specifies that the provider should use *Users* container. However, you don't have to specify the concrete conatainer (for details see this [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). For example instead of:

LDAP://testdomain.test.com/CN=Users,DC=testdomain,DC=test,DC=com

You can use:

LDAP://testdomain.test.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer. your solution to the user container problem worked!. now i can login with users from the whole domain.  i Tried your first solution with no luck. i also tried to add the username manualley like 
Roles.IsUserInRole("test",@"DOMAIN\groupname") 
but then i got a exception that the provided username had to be the same as the current username. I am starting to think that the webpage cant read the current logged in username. I tried to do 
TextBox1.Text = User.Identity.Name;
TextBox1.Text = Membership.GetUser(Login3.UserName).ToString(); 
in my loggedIn event  but no output

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you **Remove:**

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">....</authentication>
```

then you can alternatively use:

```
User.IsInRole("Students");
```